# How to create a Fixed-Size Label3D in Godot 4?

Tags: text, 3d, label, godot, godot4

I have a fixed-size 3D surface in my scene, and I want to show dynamic text on it using a `Label3D`.

My problem is that I don't know the text up-front. Currently, if the text gets too large, it just clips outside the boundaries. There would be multiple ways to stop this:

- Dynamically scale down the font to make it fit
- Show as much text as possible, then cut it off when it would overflow

How can I achieve any of the above in Godot 4? Please keep in mind that I'm dealing with a `Label3D` specifically. There is a "fixed size" flag in `Label3D`, but that just keeps the text at a constant size regardless of camera distance, which is another feature entirely and has nothing to do with what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I haven't tried this with a `Label3D`, but...

You should be able to get its current dimensions with `get_aabb`, and then use that to figure out a transformation to make it match the size you want.

For example:

```
# whatever size you want to have
var desired_size:Vector3 = get_desired_size()

# ...

# The current dimensions
var found_aabb := label_3d.global_transform * label_3d.get_aabb() 

# Compute the scale to get the desired size
var desired_scale := desired_size / found_aabb.size

# Apply the scale
label_3d.scale(desired_scale)
```

**Note**: the above code does not handle zero nor infinite values in size or scale.

Comment: Oh so you're scaling the entire object, not just the font size. That's interesting. I'll give it a shot!